# Java Fitbit by using FITBIT4j --approach through pin method

Tags: spring

```
FitbitApiCredentialsCache credentialsCache = new FitbitApiCredentialsCacheMapImpl();
        FitbitAPIEntityCache entityCache = new FitbitApiEntityCacheMapImpl();
        FitbitApiSubscriptionStorage subscriptionStore = new FitbitApiSubscriptionStorageInMemoryImpl();
        FitbitAPIClientService<FitbitApiClientAgent> fitbit = new FitbitAPIClientService<FitbitApiClientAgent>(
                new FitbitApiClientAgent(apiBaseUrl, fitbitSiteBaseUrl,
                        credentialsCache), clientConsumerKey, clientSecret,
                credentialsCache, entityCache, subscriptionStore);

        final LocalUserDetail localUser = new LocalUserDetail("1");//user means my userid
        String url = fitbit.getResourceOwnerAuthorizationURL(localUser, "");
        System.out.println("Open " + url);
        System.out.print("Enter PIN:");//What is this? Is this the userid?
        String pin = readFromUser();

        APIResourceCredentials creds = fitbit
                .getResourceCredentialsByUser(localUser);
        creds.setTempTokenVerifier(pin);
        fitbit.getTokenCredentials(localUser);

        // you can save the access_token here to reuse later
//      System.out.println("Your access_token: " + creds.getAccessToken());
//      System.out.println("Your access_token_secret: " + creds.getAccessTokenSecret());

        UserInfo profile = fitbit.getClient().getUserInfo(localUser);
        System.out.println(profile.getDisplayName() + ", member since "
                + profile.getMemberSince());

        LocalDate date = FitbitApiService.getValidLocalDateOrNull("2012-06-01");
        Sleep sleep = fitbit.getClient().getSleep(localUser,
                FitbitUser.CURRENT_AUTHORIZED_USER, date);
        System.out.println("Your sleep on " + date + ": inBed=" + sleep.getSummary().getTotalTimeInBed() + " asleep=" + sleep.getSummary().getTotalMinutesAsleep());
```

Error:

> com.fitbit.api.FitbitAPIException: 500: Something is broken. Please
>   post to the group so the Fitbit team can investigate.
>   {"errors":[{"errorType":"request","fieldName":"500","message":"Oops!
>   An unexpected error occurred. If it continues please report it at
>   help.fitbit.com."}],"success":false}

How to proceed with pin based approach ? What is the pin ? How to get the pin for a fitbit user? (as Iam a fitbit user).